# Is there any encoder for ubuntu like Windows Media Encoder

Tags: software-recommendation, multimedia, encoding, broadcasting

I`m looking for something like Windows Media Encoder.  Which I use for broadcasting.  The reason is that Windows Media Encoder series  is for windows and no support Ubuntu OS.

I want to boradcast the addressing of one person live.

Please help...

Comment: I want to boradcast the addressing of one person live.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is just broadcast a video, I would recommend using a service like [LiveStream](http://livestream.com) (my favorite) or [UStream](http://www.ustream.tv/). In fact I would setup and have both ready in case one has issues with the servers so that you can swap in case one fails. They work on all platforms. All you need is a browser and a camera (can be a webcam). You can find a couple examples in [my LiveStream channel](http://www.livestream.com/betacowork).

If you just want to transcode a file you can use [WinFF](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/winff-gui-for-ffmpeg-to-convert-file.html) or [AutoFF](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/289846-AutoFF-a-new-gui-for-FFmpeg-%28v-0-99-8%29). They are both based on [FF-Mpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

To edit video the best tools is [KDEnlive](http://kdenlive.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend VLC media player.  I would also

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
apt-cache search encoder
```

will give you an idea of the staggering list of choices.  I would also look at [Fluendo](http://www.fluendo.com)